# Vuejs Laravel validate array of inputs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

how can validate array of inputs
I need to get those validation errors and show at my form
[laravel validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE5MP.jpg)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, a community to help people with specific and clear problems. We invite you to try on yourself, read at the documentation, and try some code, then come again if you have any specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

inside controller method do like this $request->validate([
'name' => 'required','comments' => 'required' ]); in vuejs content code
@{{ allerros.comments[0] }} inside scirpt tag --- const app = new Vue({ el: '#app', data: { form: {
name : '', comments : '', }, allerros: [], success : false, },